# angular module generation mixed with other modules

Tags: angular

Hi I am using angular 7 in my application.
and i have separate modules for each but see the below image.
mixed modules are generated while ng serve.
[image]

i have many modules in my application.
Bxfviewermodule, issuemanagementmodule, clashesmanagementmodule, rulemanagementmodule.
i am using a component of issuemanagementmodule in Bxfviewermodule and i am also using a component of clashesmanagementmodule in Bxfviewermodule.

so that it is generating as shown in picture while running ng serve command in angular cli.

kindly let me know how to avoid it.

Comment: instead of posting and image add some code here

Comment: i have added some use full data please find it